# HighStock - Set the range to past 2hrs without using the rangeSelector

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a HighStock chart that renders data for the previous 24hrs, from that data I want to by default only show the last 2hrs and allow the user to drag it back if they want to see more.

I know there are defaults that can be used with the Range Selector options though I dont want this rendered on the page. An option would be to hide this also.

Here is a JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wVMGQ/2/

```
    $(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#chart').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                //selected : 1,
                enabled: false
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can always set `min` and `max` for xAxis.